# Laravel Is php-mcrypt necessary for https and Auth?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

Everything is in the title : can I use https and the Auth:: class whithout having installed php mcrypt ? (I'm on a redhat enterprise linux 6.1 on architecture s390x, it's just impossible to find pre-compiled packages).

If it's possible then I would just use Laravel whithout Mcrypt...

Answer (score 1):

mcrypt is a requirement of Laravel, you simply cannot run a laravel app without having mcrypt installed.

The following link may help with installing mcrypt:
http://injustfiveminutes.com/2012/11/23/install-php-mcrypt-extension-on-rhel-6/

Excerpt:

> The php-mcrypt extension is not available on Redhat Enterprise Linux 6
>   although some applications such as Magento or phpMyAdmin require it to
>   work properly. We can easily install it though from the Fedora Project
>   repositories.
>
> 1) Download the following RPM pacakges:
>
> wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> 2) Install them using YUM:
>
> $ yum localinstall php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> $ libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
>
> 3) Reload Apache server to load the extension up:
>
> $ service httpd restart

Comment: Hi. I already saw all that during my research, the problem is that I'm not on an i386 or x86_* architecture but on s390x and I can't find the packages for this architecture. The website fedora project gives packages for 3 architectures, none of which being what I'm looking for... Thanks though

Comment: don't suppose there's a chance you could move to another server?

Comment: Nope. Actually I found precompiled packages but they are 2010 packages, and require php 5.3.1. Supposedly laravel needss 5.3.7 so I'm kinda anxious now that something is not going to work well.

Comment: not sure if this helps? > https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/s390-builds/2012-November/091412.html